# cannot resolve symbol extras

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I am trying to send uri to another intent. However, when i try to covert back the string and display it on an image view, it shows "cannot resolve symbol extras". Please help me solve.

```
public class ConfirmUpload extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button confirmUpBtn,cancelUpBtn;
    Uri imageUri;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.confirmupload);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        confirmUpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmupload);
        cancelUpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelupload);

        imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**

```
imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUri"));
```

**or**

```
imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri"));
```